# Eclipse CDT method auto generation support

Tags: eclipse-cdt

When using other IDEs, I usually type non-existent methods which gives an unresolved method/variable error. In the screenshot below, the method Arrangement::check for the specific arguments does not exist. I was hoping to generate this method declaration automatically now after this.

[image]
Usually other IDEs gives me an option to create methods to resolve that error (This this there in IntelliJ Idea as well as Eclipse JDT, IIRC), but in Eclipse CDT, if I type in a non-existent method it gives me an error but without any way of auto generating the missing method. Now, if I press Cmd+1 on this error, I only see two options "Rename in File" or "Rename in Workspace". You can see this in the screenshot above.

I expected to see something like "create method" or "create instance method". Is there a plugin or another way which allows me to auto generate methods like this?

Answer (score 0):

I would love to have such a feature. What is possible at the moment is to implement methods out of their declaration signatures. Imagine you have the following:

```
class Arrangment {
public:
   void check(Edge* e, Edge* f, Events& heap, CirclePairSet &cpet) const;
}
```

Then set the cursor on `check`. Press *Ctrl + Shift + S* to open the *Source Code* context menu. Select *Implement method...* to create a stub with the method body.